# Facebook Error: "failed creating formpost data" upload photo to fan page

Tags: php, facebook

I want to do upload of one photo to fan page feed, but i can't,i read once that to send it, would have to be POST FORM! Its right?

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index Page Facebook</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        require('config.php');


        if($user){
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user;
?>
        <form action="facebook3.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            Message <input type="text" name="message"> <br>
            Photo: <input type="file" name="pictureFile">
                <input type="submit" value="Postar">
        </form>
<?php       
            exit();         
        }else{
    ?>
            <a href="<?php $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => $fbPermissions, 'redirect_uri' => $homeurl)); ?>">Login Facebook</a>;
    <?php       
        }
    ?>  
</body>
</html>
```

**fb.php**

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
//destroy facebook session if user clicks reset


if($_POST)
{
    //$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' =>  'manage_pages'));    
    //$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' =>  'publish_stream'));  
    @include_once("config.php");


    //Post variables we received from user
    $userPhoto  = $_FILES["pictureFile"]["tmp_name"];
    $userMessage    = $_POST["message"];

    if(strlen($userMessage)<1)
    {
        //message is empty
        $userMessage = '';
    }

        //HTTP POST request to PAGE_ID/photos with the publish_stream
        $post_url = '/228433913910358/feed';
        //posts message on page statues

        $msg_body = array(
        'source'=>'@'.$userPhoto,
        'message' => $userMessage
        );

    if ($user) {
      try {
            $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body );
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
      }
    }else{
     header("Location: index.php ");
    }

    //Show sucess message
    if($user && !empty($postResult))
     {
         echo '<html><head><title>Message Posted</title><link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head><body>';
         echo '<div id="fbpageform" class="pageform" align="center">';
         echo '<h1>Your message is posted on your facebook wall.</h1>';
         echo '<a class="button" href="'.$homeurl.'">Back to Main Page</a> <a target="_blank" class="button" href="http://www.facebook.com/'.$fbuser.'">Visit Your Page</a>';
         echo '</div>';
         echo '</body></html>';
     }
}

?>
```

so, i've tried sending by post, direct writing the path $photo, but the error persist!

**failed creating formpost data**

Comment: I'm facing the same problem when calling a Twitter API library. And in this case is a line inside the library which executes a php curl_exec instruction the one which triggers that message. It's very likely the Facebook API library you call uses the same instruction and it fails for the same reason

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late reply, but for others that might fall here...

I see 4 things that can be problematic:
1. you need to make sure $userPhoto contains a valid **server path** to your picture.
2. I used "image" instead of "source" to post an image.  (but maybe both work)
3. Since you are uploading a photo, it should upload to the //photos instead of //feed  (or to an album using /photos)
4. You need to make sure your $facebook config has fileUpload set to true or make sure to write the line:
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true); before calling the api.

So here is what the code could look like (untested code)

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
//destroy facebook session if user clicks reset

if($_POST)
{
    //$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' =>  'manage_pages'));    
    //$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' =>  'publish_stream'));  
    @include_once("config.php");

    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);


//Post variables we received from user
$userPhoto  = $_FILES["pictureFile"]["tmp_name"];
$userMessage    = $_POST["message"];

if(strlen($userMessage)<1)
{
    //message is empty
    $userMessage = '';
}

    //HTTP POST request to PAGE_ID/photos with the publish_stream
    $post_url = '/228433913910358/photos';
    //posts message on page statues

    $msg_body = array(
    'image'=>'@'.$userPhoto,
    'message' => $userMessage
    );

if ($user) {
  try {
        $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body );
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}else{
 header("Location: index.php ");
}

//Show sucess message
if($user && !empty($postResult))
 {
     echo '<html><head><title>Message Posted</title><link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head><body>';
     echo '<div id="fbpageform" class="pageform" align="center">';
     echo '<h1>Your message is posted on your facebook wall.</h1>';
     echo '<a class="button" href="'.$homeurl.'">Back to Main Page</a> <a target="_blank" class="button" href="http://www.facebook.com/'.$fbuser.'">Visit Your Page</a>';
     echo '</div>';
     echo '</body></html>';
 }
}

?>
```